convert video to audio using ffmpeg - flutter
I'm trying to convert video to audio using flutter ffmpeg kit package but it is returning ReturnCode 1 which is false
this is the command
    Directory applicationDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    outputPath = '${applicationDocDirectory.path}/output-audio-${const Uuid().v1()}.mp3';
    FFmpegKit.execute('-i ${widget.pickedVideo.path} -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 256k -f mp3 $outputPath');

is something wrong with the command?
